# Maps from field extensions of $\mathbb{Q}$ to $\mathbb{C}$

Tags: abstract-algebra, extension-field

Let $\alpha \in \mathbb{C}$ be an algebraic element on $\mathbb{Q}$ with minimal polynomial $p_\alpha$ and let $\beta \in \mathbb{C}$ be another root of $p_\alpha$. For $f \in \mathbb{Q}[x]$ let
$$\begin{split}
\sigma : \mathbb{Q}(\alpha) &\rightarrow \mathbb{C}\\
f(\alpha) &\mapsto f(\beta).
\end{split}$$

I want to know if $\sigma$ is a field homomorphism which is identity on $\mathbb{Q}$. However I don't know where to start because we only have one mapping specified in the definition.

Comment: It follows from the definition of a field homomorphism that it is the identity on the prime field, which is $\Bbb{Q}$ in this case.

Comment: @Servaes Yes I know that property but it's the homomorphism part that I struggle on.

Comment: The point is to show that $\sigma$ is well defined.  Recall that, because $\alpha$ is algebraic over $\Bbb Q$, every element of $\Bbb Q(\alpha)$ is of the form $f(\alpha)$ for some $f \in \Bbb Q[x];$ in other words, $\Bbb Q(\alpha) = \Bbb Q[\alpha]$.

Answer (score 0):

The two evaluation maps
$$\varepsilon_{\alpha}:\ \Bbb{Q}[X]\ \longrightarrow\ \Bbb{C}:\ X\ \longmapsto\ \alpha,$$
$$\varepsilon_{\beta}:\ \Bbb{Q}[X]\ \longrightarrow\ \Bbb{C}:\ X\ \longmapsto\ \beta,$$
are injective ring homomorphisms, both with kernel $p_a$. Their images in $\Bbb{C}$ are the subrings $\Bbb{Q}(\alpha)$ and $\Bbb{Q}(\beta)$, and so it follows that
$$\Bbb{Q}(\alpha)\cong\Bbb{Q}[X]/(p_a)\cong\Bbb{Q}(\beta).$$
This composition of isomorphisms maps $\alpha$ to $\beta$, so it is your map $\sigma$.